# How do you use user input as data values in chart.js?

Tags: javascript, html, css, chart.js

I'm creating a mood tracker that allows people to input the number of days they feel a certain mood. The HTML form accepts the numbers from 0-7, and accordingly I want the pie chart to dynamically shift to reflect that value. When I tried inserting the value in the data array, the whole chart disappears instead. I can't seem to figure out what the issue is, this is my code for reference:

```
``div class="form-container" style="float: left; margin-left: 170px; margin-top: 13px; text-align: center;">
            <form>

                

<!---Mood Chart--->
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/chart.js"></script>

<div class="chart-container" style=" float: right; margin-right: 150px;position: relative; height: 42vh; width: 42vw; margin-top: 8px">
<canvas id="myChart" width="100px" height="100px"></canvas>
<script>

const ctx = document.getElementById('myChart');
const myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
    type: 'pie',
    data: {
        labels: [],
        datasets: [{
            label: '# of Votes',
            data: [angryValue.value, sadValue.value, happyValue.value, anxiousValue.value, tiredValue.value, motivatedValue.value],
            backgroundColor: [
                'rgba(255, 99, 132, 0.2)',
                'rgba(54, 162, 235, 0.2)',
                'rgba(255, 206, 86, 0.2)',
                'rgba(75, 192, 192, 0.2)',
                'rgba(153, 102, 255, 0.2)',
                'rgba(255, 159, 64, 0.2)'
            ],
            borderColor: [
                'rgba(255, 99, 132, 1)',
                'rgba(54, 162, 235, 1)',
                'rgba(255, 206, 86, 1)',
                'rgba(75, 192, 192, 1)',
                'rgba(153, 102, 255, 1)',
                'rgba(255, 159, 64, 1)'
            ],
            borderWidth: 1
        }]
    },
    options: {
        scales: {
        }
    }
});

function updateChart(){
    angryValue = Number(document.getElementById('angry').value);
    sadValue = Number(document.getElementById('sad').value);
    happyValue = Number(document.getElementById('happy').value);
    anxiousValue = Number(document.getElementById('anxious').value);
    motivatedValue = Number(document.getElementById('motivated').value);
    tiredValue = Number(document.getElementById('tired').value);

    data.push({
        angry: angryValue,
        sad: sadValue,
        happy: happyValue,
        anxious: anxiousValue,
        motivated: motivatedValue,
        tired: tiredValue
    });

    chart.render();
}

var moodBtn = document.getElementById('mood-btn');
moodBtn.addEventListener('click', updateChart);


</script>
</div>``
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe this is more what you want?

```js
const moods=['Angry', 'Sad', 'Happy', 'Anxious', 'Motivated', 'Tired'];
const ctx = document.getElementById('myChart');


const cont=document.querySelector(".form-container");
cont.innerHTML=moods.map((M,i)=>{
  let m=M.toLowerCase(); 
  return `<input type="text" name="${m}" placeholder="${M}" value="${i+2}"> ${M}`;
}).join("<br>");
const inps=[...document.querySelectorAll("input")];
cont.addEventListener("input",ev=>{
 myChart.data.datasets[0].data= inps.map(el=>+el.value);
 myChart.update()
});

const myChart = new Chart( ctx, {
  type: 'pie',
  data: {
    labels: moods,
    datasets: [{
      label: '# of Votes',
      data: inps.map(el=>+el.value),
      backgroundColor: [
        'rgba(255, 99, 132, 0.2)',
        'rgba(54, 162, 235, 0.2)',
        'rgba(255, 206, 86, 0.2)',
        'rgba(75, 192, 192, 0.2)',
        'rgba(153, 102, 255, 0.2)',
        'rgba(255, 159, 64, 0.2)'
      ],
      borderColor: [
        'rgba(255, 99, 132, 1)',
        'rgba(54, 162, 235, 1)',
        'rgba(255, 206, 86, 1)',
        'rgba(75, 192, 192, 1)',
        'rgba(153, 102, 255, 1)',
        'rgba(255, 159, 64, 1)'
      ],
      borderWidth: 1
    }]
  },
  options: {
    scales: {}
  }
});
```

```css
.form-container,.chart-container  {margin: 8px; display:inline-block;}
#myChart { width:200px; height:200px;}
.form-container input {width:30px}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/chart.js"></script>

<div class="form-container"></div>
<div class="chart-container"><canvas id="myChart"></canvas></div>
```

I replaced some of your lengthy HTML markup by some generated code, based on the `moods` array. I also skipped the buttons and triggered the `update()` event by listening to `input` events on the container wrapping all input elements:

```
cont.addEventListener("input",ev=>{
 myChart.data.datasets[0].data= inps.map(el=>+el.value);
 myChart.update()
});
```

Comment: Is it possible to shift the chart beside the input box? I've tried adding margins and the float property, but I can't seem to get the chart to be on the same level with it

Comment: You can achieve something with `dispay:inline-block` already. If you want to go further you can also use [flexbox](https://www.cssportal.com/css-flexbox-generator/).

Answer (score 0):

Inside the `updateChart()` function, there is no variable named `data`. So, it looks like you're pushing some data to the uninitialized variable.

Isn't the data supposed to be pushed inside the config of chart.js? You might want to create a separate variable for storing the data so that you can push the data on the fly from other functions and just swap out the data for chart.js.

Answer (score 0):

```
<div class="form-container" style="float: left; margin-left: 170px; margin-top: 13px; text-align: center;">
            <form>

                <!---Happy--->
                <div class="mood">
                    <input type="string" name="happy" id="happy" placeholder="Happy" value="1" required>
                    <button class="mood-btn" >Enter</button>
                </div>

                <!---Angry--->
                <div class="mood">
                    <input type="string" name="angry" id="angry" placeholder="Angry" value="3" required>
                    <button class="mood-btn" >Enter</button>
                </div>

                <!---Sad--->
                <div class="mood">
                    <input type="string" name="sad" id="sad" placeholder="Sad" value="5" required>
                    <button class="mood-btn" >Enter</button>
                </div>

                <!---Motivated--->
                <div class="mood">
                    <input type="string" name="motivated" id="motivated" placeholder="Motivated & Productive" value="6"required>
                    <button class="mood-btn" >Enter</button>
                </div>

                <!---Tired--->
                <div class="mood">
                    <input type="string" name="tired" id="tired" placeholder="Tired or Burnt out" value="0" required>
                    <button class="mood-btn" >Enter</button>
                </div>

                <!---Anxious--->
                <div class="mood">
                    <input type="string" name="anxious" id="anxious" placeholder="Anxious & Stressed" value="7" required>
                    <button class="mood-btn" >Enter</button>
                </div>
            </form>
        </div>



<!---Mood Chart--->
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/chart.js"></script>

<div class="chart-container" style=" float: right; margin-right: 150px;position: relative; height: 42vh; width: 42vw; margin-top: 8px">
<canvas id="myChart" width="100px" height="100px"></canvas>
<script>
let chartData =[]
const ctx = document.getElementById('myChart');
const myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
    type: 'pie',
    data: {
        labels: ['Angry', 'Sad', 'Happy', 'Anxious', 'Motivated', 'Tired'],
        datasets: [{
            label: '# of Votes',
            data: chartData,
            backgroundColor: [
                'rgba(255, 99, 132, 0.2)',
                'rgba(54, 162, 235, 0.2)',
                'rgba(255, 206, 86, 0.2)',
                'rgba(75, 192, 192, 0.2)',
                'rgba(153, 102, 255, 0.2)',
                'rgba(255, 159, 64, 0.2)'
            ],
            borderColor: [
                'rgba(255, 99, 132, 1)',
                'rgba(54, 162, 235, 1)',
                'rgba(255, 206, 86, 1)',
                'rgba(75, 192, 192, 1)',
                'rgba(153, 102, 255, 1)',
                'rgba(255, 159, 64, 1)'
            ],
            borderWidth: 1
        }]
    },
    options: {
        scales: {
        }
    }
});

function removeData(chart) {
    chart.data.datasets.forEach((dataset) => {
        dataset.data.pop();
    });
    chart.update();
}

function addData(chart, data) {
    
    chart.data.datasets.forEach((dataset) => {
               
        dataset.data = [...data]
    });
    chart.update();
}

function updateChart(event){
    
    event.preventDefault()
    angryValue = Number(document.getElementById('angry').value);
    sadValue = Number(document.getElementById('sad').value);
    happyValue = Number(document.getElementById('happy').value);
    anxiousValue = Number(document.getElementById('anxious').value);
    motivatedValue = Number(document.getElementById('motivated').value);
    tiredValue = Number(document.getElementById('tired').value);
    
    chartData = [
        angryValue,
        sadValue,
        happyValue,
        anxiousValue,
        motivatedValue,
        tiredValue
]
    removeData(myChart)
    addData(myChart, chartData)
    
}

var moodBtn = document.querySelectorAll('.mood-btn');
moodBtn.forEach(btn => {
    btn.addEventListener('click', updateChart, false)
})
</script>
</div>
```

Comment: I changed your code quickly.

Comment: This code works for the most part, but when the data is added, the pie chart splits into multiple sections instead of grouping one mood together as one item. How do I fix that?

Comment: Welcome to SO, when answering questions, please don't just dump a load of code in - please try to explain what you have changed and how it fixes the issue

Comment: edited the code now it should work as intended. Sorry there were too many things worng and i did not have time to explain everything. If you have any questions just ask and I will explain.

Comment: Thank you so much for all your help, I appreciate it so much! If I want to add more moods, do I just make an additional variable and add it to the respective functions?

Comment: you can create new inputs with same class and add value of inputs to chartData variable

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Can I save these values in localstorage? I tried using the command ``localStorage.setItem('mood', [angryValue, sadValue, happyValue, tiredValue, motivatedValue, anxiousValue]);`` but it does not seem to work. How can I fix this?

Comment: localStorage only supports strings. Use JSON.stringify() and JSON.parse().

Comment: I tried this instead: ```const sleepJSON = JSON.stringify(chartData);
localStorage.setItem('storedData', sleepJSON);

let sleepdata = localStorage.getItem('storedData');
let input = JSON.parse(sleepdata);                               function getValue(){
    return localStorage.getItem(sleepdata)
}; ``` although nothing gets added onto the local storage.